# Spring Cloud Stream send to Kafka error control handling

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

How to catch an error writing to the Kafka topic?

```
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Processor;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;

@Component
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class Parser {

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
    public String process(Message<?> input) {

        // do smth

        // how to catch an error if sending message to 'output' topic fails
    }

}
```

Switch producer to synchronous mode.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.sync=true
```

What next? Any examples? Extend some binding impl, add some AOP magic?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to register a `KafkaProducerListener` which handles the error scenario in your case and make it available as a bean in your application.

For more info on KafkaProducerListener is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#kafka)

Also, note that usually the failed messages would be available on `errorChannel` with the channel name `error`. All the error messages are published once you have the configure the `destination` name for the error channel: `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.error.destination`.

Comment: Thanks for input. I really hope my goal is achievable with Spring Cloud Stream.

Comment: Did you find a solution using Spring Cloud Stream? There is very little documentation on error handling surprisingly, I have set up the destination error channel in my config but no errors are being published to it.

Comment: Hi, This is being addressed here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/pull/125